# expo camera eas build crashes when started video recording

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-camera

I have been working on a react-native camera app using expo camera.

According to me, on launching the camera app in expo go, video recording automatically start using onCameraReady method in expo camera but when building eas builds the app crashes.

I have used onCameraReady method to call the function record which will call recordAsync function to record the video.

```
<Camera
      ref={(ref) => {
        setcamera(ref)
      }} 
      style={{flex: 1, aspectRatio: 9/16}}
      ratio={'16:9'}
      type={type}
      onCameraReady={record}
      >
```

On initial launch the video is not recorded i have to manually click record button to record the video.

```
const record = async () => {
    setstartRecording(true)
    await camera.recordAsync()
      .then(video => {
        MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(video.uri)
      })
  }
```

Kindly help me, i am not been able to solve this.

```
import { Camera, CameraType } from 'expo-camera';
import { setStatusBarTranslucent } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Alert, Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Fontisto } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';

export default function App() {

  const [type, settype] = useState(CameraType.back)
  const [camera, setcamera] = useState()
  const [cameraStatus,setcameraStatus] = useState({})
  const [micStatus,setmicStatus] = useState({})
  const [mediaStatus,setmediaStatus] = useState({})
  const [startRecording, setstartRecording] = useState(false)
  const [timer, settimer] = useState(0)

  async function permission(){
    await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync().then(setcameraStatus)
    await Camera.requestMicrophonePermissionsAsync().then(setmicStatus)
    await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync().then(setmediaStatus)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    permission()
    setStatusBarTranslucent(true)
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null
    if(startRecording){
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        settimer( prev => prev + 1)
      }, 1000);

    }else{
      clearInterval(interval)
      settimer(0)
    }

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }

  },[startRecording])

  const record = async () => {
    setstartRecording(true)
    await camera.recordAsync()
      .then(video => {
        MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(video.uri)
      })
  }

  const toggleCameraType = () => {
    setstartRecording(false)
    settype( current => (current === CameraType.back ? CameraType.front : CameraType.back))
  }

  const stopRecording = () => {
    camera.stopRecording()
    setstartRecording(false)
  }

  return (
    <Camera
      ref={(ref) => {
        setcamera(ref)
      }} 
      style={{flex: 1, aspectRatio: 9/16}}
      ratio={'16:9'}
      type={type}
      onCameraReady={record}
      >
        <View style={{position: 'absolute', flexDirection: 'row', bottom: 0, padding: 48, justifyContent: 'space-between', width: Dimensions.get('window').width}}>
          <View
           style={{
            width: 61, 
            height: 61, 
            borderWidth: 3, 
            borderColor: 'white', 
            borderRadius: 100, 
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
            }}>
            <Text
             style={{
              color: 'white',
              fontSize: 34,
              fontWeight: 'bold'
              }}>{timer}</Text>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={startRecording ? () => stopRecording() : () => setstartRecording(true)}>
            <Fontisto name="record" size={64} color={ startRecording ? "red" : "white"} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleCameraType}>
            <MaterialIcons name="flip-camera-android" size={64} color="white" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        
    </Camera>      
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});
```

I am making a camera app which automatically starts recording video using the expo-camera library.

On launching the application the video recording must start immediately after mounting the camera component.

It works well on the expo go app but when building eas build and installing the apk on a physical device, the app crashes or the app does not record video at all.

Comment: are you sure you have given the camera permission?

Comment: on android, you need to add manifest

Comment: yes, the camera have permissions, the camera is working but it is not recording automatically when i start the app. I have to press the recording button to record the video.